# How to add a tag on a aliased service?

Tags: symfony

I defined the following service:

```
my_project.widget_listing_content_resolver:
    class: MyProject\Widget\ListingBundle\Resolver\WidgetListingContentResolver
    arguments:
        - "@router"
    tags:
        - { name: my_project.widget_content_resolver, alias: Listing }
```

And I want to declare an alias of this service, with a different tag:

```
my_project.widget_domain_operations_content_resolver:
    alias: my_project.widget_listing_content_resolver
    tags:
        - { name: my_project.widget_content_resolver, alias: DomainOperations }
```

But in my ContentResolverChain, the service aliased "DomainOperations" is not present. Is there a way to solve this ?

EDIT: 
I tried the following configuration:

```
my_project.widget_listing_content_resolver:
    class: MyProject\Widget\ListingBundle\Resolver\WidgetListingContentResolver
    arguments:
        - "@router"
    tags:
        - { name: my_project.widget_content_resolver, alias: Listing }
        - { name: my_project.widget_content_resolver, alias: DomainOperations }
```

It results that the "my_project.widget_listing_content_resolver" service is only tagged as "Listing". My problem now is: "How to tag a service with multiple tag aliases"

Comment: Alias allows you to create another **name** for the service, not change its definition. You probably want to create a new service.

Comment: I want to define a new name, plus a new tag to the service "my_project.widget_domain_operations_content_resolver", but I will use the same class and so the same arguments. Alias seemed to be a good alternative to re-declare the same class with same arguments in a second service, just to add a tag.

Comment: I digged a litte bit, and it seems that tagging an aliases does work, but the tag name is the same so the tag is overwrited, that's why the tag alias "DomainOperation" does not apprear

Comment: I found out where was my error, in definitive, a service alias can create another name AND can add some tags on the aliased service. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to that problem. The service alias was tagged as espected, but the additionnal tag was not read by my CompilerPass:

This was the errored CompilerPass:

```
        $taggedServices = $container->findTaggedServiceIds(
            'my_project.widget_content_resolver'
        );

        foreach ($taggedServices as $id => $attributes) {
            $definition->addMethodCall(
                'addResolver',
                array($attributes[0]['alias'], new Reference($id))
            );
        }
```

As you see, it took only the first alias found ($attributes[0])

I had to change it to:

```
        $taggedServices = $container->findTaggedServiceIds(
            'my_project.widget_content_resolver'
        );

        foreach ($taggedServices as $id => $attributes) {
            foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
                $definition->addMethodCall(
                    'addResolver',
                    array($attribute['alias'], new Reference($id))
                );
            }
        }
```